# How to obtain proportion of a boolean value for different categories in the same table

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I am new to python and this is a part of an assignment for a course I am taking. I am supposed to find a group (there are 10+ groups) that has the highest proportion of Value A (it is a boolean - A or B only).

I have tried finding the total number of values for each group and and the count of A and B for each group. I was hoping if I could some how write a simple division formula to obtain each group's proportion of Value A but I am stuck. In fact, I probably am not even taking a correct approach from the beginning.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header = None)

Data.head()
0  Group  Value
1   1       A
2   1       A
3   1       B
4   3       A
5   3       B 
6   2       A
7   2       B
8   2       A
9   2       A
10  4       B

Data.groupby('Group')['Value'].size()
# to get the total number of values applicable

Data.groupby(['Group', 'Value']).size()
# to get the count of rows for each Value (A and B only) for each Group (10+ groups)
```

Please excuse my explanation if I am not making it clear enough. I will try to address better if needed. I am hoping to learn how to obtain the percentage of Value A for each Group.

Eg.

```
    Group1 61% (or 0.61)
    Group2 54%
    Group3 49$ and so on...
```

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input data?

Comment: Group (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15), Value (A B)

Comment: I tried to copy in data.head(3) but it looks too messy. Is this enough or is there a better way to show an example of data in to this comment block?

Comment: You can edit you original question, yes

Comment: I just edited the original question and added an example input dataset. Hope this helps... I am sorry I cannot share the actual dataset due to confidentiality issues.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this does the job (I now it doesn't look pretty)

```
for group in [1,2,3,4]:
    if 'A' in Data.loc[Data['Group'] == group].groupby(['Value']).count().index:
       proportion = (Data.loc[Data['Group'] == group].groupby(['Value']).count()/
                    Data.loc[Data['Group'] == group].count()).loc['A','Group']
       print('Group'+ str(group) + ' ' + str(proportion))
    else:
        print('Group'+ str(group) + ' ' + str(0))


Group1 0.6666666666666666
Group2 1.0
Group3 0.3333333333333333
Group4 0
```